# Nextjs 13.4- in Vercel Deployment SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, vercel, next.js13, app-router

I have pushed my code to git hub, a simple E-commerce Admin panel.
I have set my BaseUrl as in Development as NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL=http://localhost:3000 inside (.env.development.local) and In Build at local as NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL=localhost:3000 inside (.env)

Full Link for LOCAL DEV AND BUILD :-
dev:
BASE URL http://localhost:3000

Build
BASE URL http://localhost:3000

For Local Development Since its using http.

```
export function getBaseUrl(){

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {

    return `${process?.env?.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL.toString()}`
  }
  For Local build using http.
  return `http://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL.toString()}`
}
const baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
console.log("BASE URL",baseUrl) //Logged: BASE URL http://localhost:3000
```

both are working Fine on Development and build Locally. Cool!!

Now on Vercel Deployment:
i have Changed the function getBaseUrl() to https://

```js
export function getBaseUrl(){

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {

    return `${process?.env?.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL.toString()}`
  }
  For Local build using http.
  return `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL.toString()}`
}
```

uploaded to git
and while Building got the log

BASE URL https://zaffrano-dashboard-6vek3o99k-muadpn.vercel.app

So its replacing the build URL automatically by vercel NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL to the baseurl

The Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6662:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6636:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1236:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error occurred prerendering page "/categories". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6662:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6636:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1236:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
- info Generating static pages (12/16)
component/ui/navbar/navLink shipping
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6662:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6636:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1236:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error occurred prerendering page "/products". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6662:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6636:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1236:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6662:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6636:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1236:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error occurred prerendering page "/products/add". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6662:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6636:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1236:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
- info Generating static pages (16/16)
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /categories/page: /categories
    /products/add/page: /products/add
    /products/page: /products
```

Here is How i fetch the data:

**PATH:-src/helpers/Handlers/categories.jsx**

```js
import { getBaseUrl } from "@/lib/utils";

const baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
export async function getCategoryData() {
  console.log("BASE URL",baseUrl)
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/category`, {
      method: "GET",
      next: { tags: ["category"] },
    });
    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
}
export async function getCategoryDataById(id) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/category/${id}`, {
      method: "GET",
      next: { tags: ["CategoryId"] },
    });
    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
}
```

**PATH:-src/helpers/Handlers/ProductHandlers.jsx**

```
import { getBaseUrl } from "@/lib/utils";
const baseUrl = getBaseUrl()
export async function getProductDatas() {
  console.log(baseUrl)
  const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/product`, {
    method: "GET",
    next: { tags: ["product"] },
  });
  return res.json();
}

export async function getProductById(id) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/product/${id}`, {
      method: "GET",
      next: { tags: [id] },
    });
    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("getProductById",error)
  }
}
```

**PATH:-src/app/products/page.jsx**

```
import RedirectLinks from "@/components/ui/button/Links/RedirectLinks";
import { ProductTable } from "@/components/ui/table/ProductTable";
// import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
// const { ProductTable } = dynamic(import("@/components/ui/table/ProductTable"), {
//   ssr: false,
//   loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
// });
export const metadata = {
  title: "Product",
  description: "Product",
};
const ProductPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-end ">
        <RedirectLinks
          toLink="/products/add"
          titles="Add Product"
          titleClass="font-medium"
          Divclasses={"rounded-sm"}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
          <ProductTable /> // THIS IS FETCHING DATA FROM ProductHandler
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductPage;
```

**PATH:-src/components/ui/table/ProductTable.jsx**

```
import { getProductDatas } from "@/helpers/Handlers/ProductHandlers";
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";

export const ProductTable = async () => {
  const { data } = await getProductDatas();
  return (
    <div className=" border-2 rounded-xl my-5">
      <table className="w-full">
     ......
     ......
     ......
```

Samilar Structure for Categories.

I have tried many of stuff:- i figured out its not giving me the data from backend as expected. soo have added to (data && data.map()) now its Deployed to the server and when i go to product/id its working but product itself is not rendering to the server. and still get the update. but my data is not rendering as expected.

some id to test for categories:-
goes under zaffrano.vercel.app/categories/[id]
64fe764bb226d93ac1f9d440
64ff3ec6b501a99ce571915e
65037834613a866e75670245
65043efc9b7e25271046e774
some id to test for products:-
goes under zaffrano.vercel.app/products/[id]
6503793d0eab3b840d18d999
6503789b613a866e75670268
65035f529459b343e4413720
incase you are wondering the url i typed first is https://zaffrano-dashboard-6vek3o99k-muadpn.vercel.app
and how its zaffrano.vercel.app i changed it.
writing this Article after trying different things.
Thanks <3

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am also facing the same problem snd unable to understand the root cause.

Comment: @DibyenduSaha Ohh yes. Sorry to update and close the question. The answer is to this is not to fetch the any Next.js Endpoint from the server side Rendering, Rather write your logic on the server side itself, and don't create a endpoint for it. just call your db on where your data is needed.